# How many outcomes of a coin being flipped 12 times have exactly 4 heads?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I know that there are a total of 4096 possible outcomes of tossing a coin twelve times, but I do not know how to calculate the number of possible outcomes with exactly 4 heads, with at least 2 heads, or at most 8 heads.

Answer (score 1):

*Exactly 4 heads:* This boils down to choosing 4 "spots" out of the 12 "spots" to put the 4 heads outcomes. That is, $\binom{12}{4}$.

*At least 2 heads*: $2^{12}- \binom{12}{0} - \binom{12}{1}$ subtracting the possibility of 0 or 1 heads.

*At most 8 heads:* $2^{12}- \binom{12}{12} - \binom{12}{11} - \binom{12}{10} - \binom{12}{9}$ subtracting the possibility of 9 or more heads.

Comment: What do the two numbers in the parentheses mean? I haven't seen that before

Comment: @Craig http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient One way to calculate them is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ where $n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \dotsb \cdot 2 \cdot 1$.