# A coin is flipped 14 times. How many different outcomes have at most 10 heads?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I followed the pattern here but it still resulted in my problem being incorrect. [How many outcomes of a coin being flipped 12 times have exactly 4 heads?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600919/how-many-outcomes-of-a-coin-being-flipped-12-times-have-exactly-4-heads)

(1 pt) A coin is tossed 14 times. 
d)   How many different outcomes have at most 10 heads?

I did $2^{14}-\left(\frac{14!}{14!}+\frac{14!}{13!}+\frac{14!}{12!}+\frac{14!}{11!}\right)$, which translates to how many flips have at least $4$ tails.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: If we flipped three times are $011$ and $110$ the same outcome or different? In other words, does order matter?

Comment: Can you explain where all you terms came from? What are all the factorial terms counting?

Comment: @AlvinLepik I know that you use factorial when order matters but I couldn't find a way to do it with power either.

Comment: @kccu The factorial terms are the amount of flips with at least 4 tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you did *not* follow the result from the other post. You're using permutations, rather than combinations. Instead, it should be $$2^{14}-\frac{14!}{14!0!}-\frac{14!}{13!1!}-\frac{14!}{12!2!}-\frac{14!}{11!3!}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Question though. I thought I was suppose to use the formula c(n,r) -> n!/((n-r)!r!) for when order is important. Why is that not the case here?

Comment: That is for when order is *not* important, such as in this situation. When order matters, we use $$P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways of getting $0$ head is $14\choose{0}$. The number of ways of getting $1$ head is $14\choose1$.....The number of ways of getting $n$ head is $14\choose{n}$ with $1\le{n}\le{10}$.

so answer is $\sum_{i=0}^{10}$$14\choose{i}$.

which comes to 15914 if you use the formula for the ${n\choose k}={\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the binomial distribution to model the coin flips as $X\sim B(14,\frac12)$. Then the number of outcomes is $2^{14}$ so the number of required outcomes is given by
$$\begin{align}
2^{14}\cdot P(X\le 10)
&=2^{14}\cdot(1-P(X\ge 11))\\
&=2^{14}\cdot\left(1-\Bigg(\overbrace{\binom{14}{11}\left(\frac12\right)^{14}+\binom{14}{12}\left(\frac12\right)^{14}+\binom{14}{13}\left(\frac12\right)^{14}+\binom{14}{14}\left(\frac12\right)^{14}}^{P(X=11)+P(X=12)+P(X=13)+P(X=14)}\Bigg)\right)\\
&=2^{14}\cdot\left(1-\binom{14}{11}\cdot2^{-14}-\binom{14}{12}\cdot2^{-14}-\binom{14}{13}\cdot2^{-14}-\binom{14}{14}\cdot2^{-14}\right)\\
&=2^{14}-\binom{14}{11}-\binom{14}{12}-\binom{14}{13}-\binom{14}{14}\\
&=2^{14}-\frac{14!}{11!\cdot3!}-\frac{14!}{12!\cdot2!}-\frac{14!}{13!\cdot1!}-\frac{14!}{14!\cdot0!}\\
&=15914\\
\end{align}$$